# Emacs cannot start from spotlight, "Method 'zsh' is not known"

Tags: start-up

I just buy a new macbook and I want to move my old working env to it. I used `emacs-plus@27.0.91` which was installed by homebrew:

```
d12frosted/emacs-plus/emacs-plus@27: stable 27.0.91, HEAD
/usr/local/Cellar/emacs-plus@27/27.0.91 (4,014 files, 131MB) *
  Built from source on 2020-07-15 at 20:36:39 with: --with-no-titlebar --with-jansson --with-mailutils --with-modern-icon
```

I cloned my old `.emacs.d` config repo and it works well from terminal using both `-nw`, and without `-nw`.

But when start Emacs from spotlight, Emacs will give me an error message `Method 'zsh' is not known/Method 'zsh' is not known/tramp-error: Method 'zsh' is not known`, the Emacs window shows the following error, and press any key now will also only triggers this error.

I tried to `bug-hunt` the init file, but found no error.

Btw, no `zsh` is found in my `.emacs.d`, though I am using `zsh` in terminal. And no settings relative to `tramp`.

Here is my .emacs.d : https://github.com/cmal/.emacs.d
Can you help me out?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your error message clearly states that this is a "tramp-error".  If you want the author/maintainer of Tramp to have a look at your question, then use a tag that states "tramp" (a tag with "init-file" will not likely get the Tramp maintainer's attention unless he reads all the questions) ; i.e., edit your question and use the relevant tag.  Consider editing your question to add your relevant settings that tell "tramp" where your `zsh` executable is located, and so forth.  Maybe your old computer used a different shell file name, and/or maybe it is now in a different location ...

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question. But still not find any relative settings.

Comment: Thanks to the tag `tramp`, I've found the question (I'm the Tramp maintainer). Run `M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections`, this should fix your issue.

Comment: If your question is about not being able to start Emacs from Spotlight, then it can't have anything to do with your init file or Tramp or anything else that takes effect after start-up. Try starting Emacs from Spotlight using `emacs -Q` (no init file). Please edit your question to remove everything that's not relevant. Thx.

Comment: @Michael Albinus I've run `M-x tramp-cleanup-all-connections` , started from spotlight, still has this problem. `emacs -Q` will work fine. I've NEVER used tramp or have any configurations about tramp on this machine. I've found if I start a emacs frame from hammerspoon using `/usr/local/bin/emacsclient -n -c -a ""` will also got the `zsh` error.
Is this related to `emacs-plus@27.0.91`?

Comment: I recommend to bisect your init files, because starting `emacs -Q` works. Likely something in `recentf` or `desktop` or a similar package data file is corrupted. You'll find it this way. Alternatively, you could set `debug-on-error` to `t`, in order to see the backtrace.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus Thanks for your advice, I'll have another try.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus I've biset the init file, and found this line in one of the required files: `(add-to-list
 'load-path
 (replace-regexp-in-string
  "\n" "/share/emacs/site-lisp"
  (shell-command-to-string "opam config var prefix")))
` because I did not install the ocaml env, this evals to `"zsh:1: command not found: opam/share/emacs/site-lisp"`, so this is where `zsh` comes from. funny. I should add some code to test whether ocaml exists. Thanks a lot for your advice.